# Sorting output based on row value with Linux bash

Tags: linux, unix-text-processing

I need to print the whole output sorted based on 'Resident Set Size' value.

Process: wccpd
Memory (bytes)
Total Virtual Size  29.5

Resident Set Size    4.0

Process: writeback
Memory (bytes)
Total Virtual Size   0

Resident Set Size    0

Process: zxfrd
Memory (bytes)
Total Virtual Size  71.3

Resident Set Size    3.9

Answer (score 0):

`perl` is pretty good at this sort of thing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.12.0;
$/ = "";  # enable "paragraph mode"

my @f;
while(<DATA>) {
    m/Resident Set Size (.*)/;
    push @f, [$1, $_];
}
say $_->[1] foreach sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @f;


__DATA__
Process: wccpd
Memory (bytes)
Total Virtual Size 29.5
Resident Set Size 4.0

Process: writeback
Memory (bytes)
Total Virtual Size 0
Resident Set Size 0

Process: zxfrd
Memory (bytes)
Total Virtual Size 71.3
Resident Set Size 3.9
```

The idea is pretty simple.  Setting `$/` (aka `$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR` or `$RS`) to the empty string puts `perl` in "paragraph mode" where records are separated by blank lines.  We then read the file one record at a time and parse each record to match "Resident Set Size" and find the value on which you wish to sort.  We then push an array reference consisting of the value in [0] and the whole record in [1].  Then you use the `<=>` operator to compare the records in the sort function.

If you have your input in the file `input` and want to execute something like this directly, you can do:

```
perl -00 -nE 'm/Resident Set Size (.*)/; push @f, [$1, $_]}
    { say $_->[1] foreach sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @f' input
```

This is precisely the same as the above script, where the `-n` performs the `while(<>)` loop and `-00` enables paragraph mode.  The oddly mismatchted `} {` are a `perl` idiom for use with `-n`.  The `-n` flag basically puts a `while(<>){ }` loop around the entire script, and we are closing that loop with the first `}` and matching its closing brace with the (seemingly unmatched) `{`.